# Does onLocationChanged is called when class implements LocationListener?

Tags: android

I can't understand why onLocationChanged in not called in an Activity, while it is called in a service. Suppose I have a service:

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener{

    @override
    public void onCreate() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { //it is called
        //do something with location 
    }
}
```

And I have an Activity:

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { //it is not called
        //do something with location 
    }
}
```

Is that because I haven't requested location updates in this activity? Why should I request it, if it was already done in the service.
Also, how should I spread my location through application correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is done in your service, that means you need to start that service from the activity. If you have an activity like the one you are using with no request to location updates it onLocationChanged will not work.

This is the part where it actually calls the location updates

```
requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, this);
```

I see that you are trying to use the service in the background and received updates in the activity. Your possible solution is to send broadcast from the service inside onLocationChanged method, and receive it in the activity.

so from your service:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.myapp.LOCATION_CHANGED");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

and your activity

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // do something
}
```